# R: Reclin Package: Is there a way to keep the weights generated in score_problink() and used in select_n_to_m() after using the link() function?

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am trying to perform a record linkage on 2 datasets containing company names. While Reclin does a very good job indeed, the linked data will need some manual cleaning and because I will most likely have to clean about 3000 rows in a day or 2 it would be great to keep the weights generated in the reclin process as shown below:

```
CH_ecorda_to_Patstat_left <- pair_blocking(companies_x, companies_y) %>%
  compare_pairs(by= "nameor", default_comparator = jaro_winkler()) %>%
  score_problink() %>%
  select_n_to_m()%>%
  link(all_x=TRUE, all_y = FALSE)
```

I know these weights are still kept up until I use the link() function. I would like to add the weights based to compare the variable "nameor" so I can use these weights to order my data in ascending order, from smallest weight to biggest weight to find mistakes in the attempted match quicker.

For context: I need to find out how many companies_x have handed in patents in the patent data base companies_y. I don´t need to know how often they handed them in, just if there are any at all. So I need matches of x to y, however I don´t know the true number of matches and not every companies_x company will have a match, so some manual cleaning will be necessary as n_to_m forces a match for each entry even if there should be none.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
weight<-problink_em(paired)  
paired<-score_problink(paired, weight)
```

You'll have the result stored as `weight` now.